# Networking, ping tool

Tags: networking, ping, icmp

I have pinged many websites using ping command, and got the reply. Now I want to find the distance in meters between my PC and the public web server. Do you know how to find the distance between a target and my computer ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at all, there is no way to translate ping times to meters. I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible unless you know physically the distance. 
As you know, if you trace a destination, it will try to reach it accordingly to the most quick path. So there is no way you can know a distance from you and a server just because of ping.

Comment: I think it is possible to use an internet service for that purpose, but unfortunately I don't know which service.if anyone knows, it would be better :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `traceroute` command and one of the sites for find geolocation of an IP address to each of points.